# Moving structure containing reference into static closure doesn't work

Tags: rust, scope, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm creating a structure containing a reference and a function that gets a closure with `'static` lifetime:

```
pub struct RefStruct<'a> {
    pub mref: &'a u32,
}

fn run<F>(mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut() -> () + 'static,
{
    f();
}
```

I create an integer `num` which lives throughout the execution of `main`:

```
fn main() {
    let num = 32;
    ...
}
```

Now I want to create a `struct` referencing it. If I create it inside the `'static` closure, it works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let num = 32;

    run(move || {
        let rstruct = RefStruct { mref: &num }; // Ok!
        print!("{}", rstruct.mref);
    });
}
```

However, if I create the `struct` in the `main` function scope and then move it into the closure it doesn't:

```
fn main() {
    let num = 32;
    let rstruct = RefStruct { mref: &num };

    run(move || {
        print!("{}", rstruct.mref);
    });
}
```

I get

```
error[E0597]: `num` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:37
   |
15 |       let rstruct = RefStruct { mref: &num };
   |                                       ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
16 | /     run(move || {
17 | |         print!("{}", rstruct.mref);
18 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `num` is borrowed for `'static`
19 |   }
   |   - `num` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to previous error
```

However, it seems to me that the two scopes should be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically in the first case, `num` is referenced in the closure, so it is captured and moved inside the closure. It becomes `'static` and the reference is valid.

In the second case, `num` is not captured, because the identifier is never used in the closure. So, the reference becomes static while `num` is not.